# Notify new application version with browser service workers

Tags: polymer, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I build an html/js application (a progressive web app) with Polymer and  polymer-cli and the well generated service-worker for caching and offline.

I wonder how to notify the user when a new version of the application is available and invite him to restart browser.

any ideas ?

**Edit**

a talk at IO2016 where Eric Bidel talk about service worker and notify user about new version of an application :
https://youtu.be/__KvYxcIIm8?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILe6_eGvDN3GyiodoV3qNSC&t=1510

Need to check the google IO Web source code

Comment: Web-apps support [push-notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/). But this seems wrong to use for notifying the user that the app has been updated. And why would you want the user to "restart browser"? Service worker will do this automatically when it detects any changes...

Comment: What i see and understand is that the service worker doesn't restart application, it just update itself and the cache when the cache download is completed you've have to restart the app to get the new application in cache ... I just remembered a talk in IO where Eric Bidel talk about this, i'll try to find this talk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References:

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle
- https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud899

  ```
  // page script
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker
          .register('/sw.js')
          .then(function(registration) {
              console.info('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope:', registration.scope);

             // if there's no controller, this page wasn't loaded
             // via a service worker, so they're looking at the latest version.
             // In that case, exit early
             if (!navigator.serviceWorker.controller) return;

             // if there's an updated worker already waiting, update
             if (registration.waiting) {
                 console.info('show toast and upon click update...');
                 registration.waiting.postMessage({ updateSw: true });
                 return;
             }

             // if there's an updated worker installing, track its
             // progress. If it becomes "installed", update
             if (registration.installing) {
                 registration.addEventListener('statechange', function(){
                     if (registration.installing.state == 'installed'){
                         console.info('show toast and upon click update...');
                         registration.installing.postMessage({ updateSw: true });
                         return;          
                     }
                 });
             }

             // otherwise, listen for new installing workers arriving.
             // If one arrives, track its progress.
             // If it becomes "installed", update
             registration.addEventListener('updatefound', function(){
                 let newServiceWorker = registration.installing;

                 newServiceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', function() {
                     if (newServiceWorker.state == 'installed') {
                         console.info('show toast and upon click update...');
                         newServiceWorker.postMessage({ updateSw: true });           
                     }
                 });
             });
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
              console.info('ServiceWorker registration failed:', error);
          });


        navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', function() {
            window.location.reload();
        });
      }

  });

  // sw script
  self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      if (e.data.updateSw){
          self.skipWaiting();
      }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to IO team .. we need to check if the current service-worker becomes redundant

```
// Check to see if the service worker controlling the page at initial load
// has become redundant, since this implies there's a new service worker with fresh content.
if (navigator.serviceWorker && navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
   navigator.serviceWorker.controller.onstatechange = function(event) {
     if (event.target.state === 'redundant') {
       // Define a handler that will be used for the next io-toast tap, at which point it
       // be automatically removed.
       const tapHandler = function() {
         window.location.reload();
       };

       if (IOWA.Elements && IOWA.Elements.Toast &&
          IOWA.Elements.Toast.showMessage) {
            IOWA.Elements.Toast.showMessage(
            'A new version of this app is available.', tapHandler, 'Refresh',
            null, 0); // duration 0 indications shows the toast indefinitely.
       } else {
         tapHandler(); // Force reload if user never was shown the toast.
       }
     }
  };
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is necessary anymore, since the `polymer-cli` generates the service worker at build time and I'm pretty sure this kind of code is included. As for referencing the IOWA app... the preferred template app is the [shop app](https://github.com/Polymer/shop/), which does **not** include the `redundant` state check.

Comment: I think the shop app is not include the redundant check because it's not a wanted behavior. Most of the time service-worker is use for caching and offline : it's what polymer-cli build an offline and caching worker. But if you care that your users use the latest version of your app you need to handle it. It would be a bad user experience if the browser reload itself after a cache update.